# When fighting bosses, what controls the minion spawns?

Tags: torchlight-2

I just fought General Grell and it was a longer than normal fight. His minions kept respawning during the fight. What makes the minions spawn?

- Is it timed? Say, every 30 seconds a new wave comes
- Is it based on the percent of the damage done to the boss? Every X percent a new wave comes?
- Is it based on the number of minions left to left? IF the number of minions alive drops to say, less than 4, it spawns new minions?

Comment: Thus far, I can say for the 2 boss slaves at the slave camp it's not timed. I ran around them for awhile and the minions did not increase in number. If I get a chance to test more I'll post a full answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the boss will summon more minions after a certain time interval. If the new number of minions would be higher than the minion cap for that boss, old minions are killed to make room for the new ones.

Comment: This has been tested on 2 bosses thus far, One-eyed willy and the twin boss at the slave camp.